# Convertion of Mat to 2d array and access the pixel values in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, mat

I have converted a Mat to 2d arrays in c++ using opencv. To be able to make sure that I am getting the same pixel values in both containers(Mat and array) I tried this:

```
cout << xma.at<float>(4,11) << endl;

cout << xma_[4][11] << endl;
```

xma is Mat and xma_ is the 2d array.

The result I get are very far from each other!

Is the way that I am trying to access the pixel values correct?

And here is the code:

```
Mat imrgb = imread("src.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);    
Mat bgr[3];   
split(imrgb, bgr);

double average[600][800];

for(int j=0; j<=599;j++ )
{
   for(int i=0; i<=799; i++)
   {
        average[j][i] =((((float)(bgr[0].at<uchar>(j,i)) + (float)(bgr[1].at<uchar>(j,i)) +(float)(bgr[2].at<uchar>(j,i))))/(3));
   } 
}    

for(int j=0; j<=599;j++ )
{
    for(int i=0; i<=799; i++)
    {
        average[j][i] = average[j][i] / 255;
    }  
 }       

src = Mat(600, 800, CV_64F, &average);

vector<float>gx;
vector<float>mult_vec;
for(int i=0; i<vec_first.size(); i++)
{
      mult_vec.push_back(vec1[i] * vec2[i]);     
}

for(int i=0; i<mult_vec.size(); i++)
{
    gx.push_back((exp(-mult_vec[i] / C); 
}

for(int i = 0; i < gx.size(); i++)
{
     gy.push_back(gx[i]);
}

Mat gyMat=Mat(5, 1, CV_32F);
memcpy(gyMat.data, gy.data(), gy.size()*sizeof(float));
Mat gykernel;
cv::transpose(gy, gykernel);

filter2D(src, xma, -1 , gykernel, Point( -1, -1 ), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );

for(j=0; j<=599;j++ )
{
   for(i=0; i<=799; i++)
   {
      xma_[j][i] =(double)(xma.at<uchar>(j,i));

   }
}
```

First I have read an rgb image, then I have splitted it into 3 channels and tried to get the average of the 3 channels. I have then divided the values to 255 to get the gray scale image.

Comment: The problem is likely in the part of code you didn't show. [MCVE] please.

Comment: You are right. Now I have edited the question.

Comment: Note the "Complete" part -- that means something that will compile. This won't, since there are no includes, no `main` (and code is outside a function), undefined `src`, `vec_first`, `vec1`, `vec2`, `C`, `gy`, `xma`, `xma_`... and almost everything from OpenCV or standard library code is not namespace qualified.

Comment: That said, `src` is obviously a `cv::Mat` with one channel and elements of type `CV_64F` -- i.e. `double`. You call `filter2D` with dtype of -1, meaning `xma` will have have the same datatype as source -- i.e. `double`. Hence `xma.at<float>(4,11)` is wrong, and so is `xma.at<uchar>(j,i)` -- you need to use the same type as is held by the `Mat`, so `xma.at<double>(j,i)`.

Comment: @DanMašek changing the float to double which not change anything!

Comment: @DanMašek Do you know any function in opencv for converting rgb image to grayscale?

Comment: [`cv::cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab)?

Comment: @DanMašek cv::cvtColor does not work for me. I would like to get the average of the 3 channels and divide them to 255 to be able to have the pixel values between 0 and 1. The result of cvColor does not give me the pixel values between 0 and 1.

Comment: Well, you asked for conversion from RGB to grayscale, so that's what you use for that purpose (Note that going to grayscale is not a simple average, it's weighed). | If you want to convert to a different type (float) (possibly scaling/offsetting it at the same time), you have [`cv::Mat::convertTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b).

Comment: And if you really need a simple mean of the 3 components, then a `cv::reduce` together with couple of `cv::Mat::reshape`s should do the job. Reshape to 1 channel, and `width*height` rows (so that you have 3 columns, and each pixel takes 1 row), then reduce to single column, and reshape back to `height` rows.